# Agregar un "id" a un elemento creado en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Estoy comenzando con PHP y tengo una duda, quizás un poco básica, pero la verdad es que no puedo resolverla. Lo que pretendo hacer es crear algo como un semáforo donde cada cierto tiempo se vayan cambiando las imágenes, según el color que tengan en la base de datos como se ve en la imagen de abajo.

[image: Tabla estación]

Tengo este pequeño código en PHP que me permite crear los círculos que pretendo mostrar en mi página web:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $cant_est; $i++) {

    if ($estacion['color'] == 'verde') {
        ?><img src="<?= base_url() ?>/images/verde.png"> <?php
    } elseif ($estacion['color'] == 'rojo') {
        ?><img src="<?= base_url() ?>/images/rojo.png"> <?php
    } elseif ($estacion['color'] == 'amarillo') {
        ?><img src="<?= base_url() ?>/images/amarillo.png"><?php
    }
}
?>
```

Lo que hace ese código es mostrar la cantidad de círculos, según la cantidad de estaciones que tengo (en este caso 2 estaciones) por lo que en mi página me aparece así:

[image: Estaciones]

¿Cómo asignarle un *"id"* a cada círculo que se crea? Por ejemplo, quiero cambiar el color de alguna de las dos estaciones en mi base de datos, pero no sé cómo poder identificarlas.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres meter la `id_estacion` de la base de datos, debes hacer un `foreach` en vez de un `for`:

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $estacion) {

  echo '<img id="'.$estacion['id_estacion'].'" src="'.base_url().'/images/'.$estacion['color'].'.png">';    
}
```

De esta manera no necesitas compararlo tampoco con un `if else if`, ya que te devuelve el mismo nombre del `color` de la base datos: `$estacion['color'].png`.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del ciclo, como mismo le asignas el src a cada imagen, agrégale el id de la misma basado en el número de la iteración

```
<img id="<?php echo $i ?>" src="<?php echo  base_url()."/images/verde.png" ?>">
```

Deteniéndome un poco, el id no sería el número de la iteración, sino el identificador en la BD de la "estación"

Comment: Tienes razón, el id sería el identificador de la estación en la BD pero la verdad es que no he podido asignarle ese id en específico. Quizás hice mal la pregunta...Gracias de todas formas por responder.